# fair die or not, from 3D printer

Tags: statistics

I made a 3D printed die today, but depending on the heat applied, it may or may not be a "fair" die (i.e. have an equal chance of landing on each face).

I have just tried rolling it 150 times.  The frequency results came out to:

$$ \begin{array}{c|c} \hline
1's &  21 \\
\hline
 2's & 30 \\ 
\hline
3's & 23 \\
\hline
4's & 31 \\
\hline
5's & 21 \\ 
\hline
6's & 24 \\ 
\hline
\end{array} $$

How would I calculate the chance that this die is fair?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "Laplacian die."  Do you perhaps mean a "fair die" (one in which each side is equally likely to appear when tossed)?  Otherwise, could you please define your terms?

Comment: What is a Laplacian die?  Is it a fair die?  If so, you can't, if you're a Bayesian; you need a prior.  Otherwise, you try to refute the null hypothesis that the die is fair, and evaluate the probability of obtaining the results you did with something like the chi-squared test.

Comment: What you can compute is the chance that a result as lopsided as this (if not more so) will arise using a fair die.  That is not strictly the same thing as asking for the probability that your die is fair, given the result you reported.

Comment: i guess i mean a fair die, i thought/learned laplacian die is the same. @hardmath thats a start, how would i do that?

Comment: To die or not to die: that's the question.

Comment: The $\chi^2$-value here is $3.92$, which is absolutely non-significiant. There is no reason to doubt the fairness of the die.

Comment: I like the question. I certainly don't have the means to 3D print a cube, nor the patience to roll the thing 150 times and record the results, so kudos!

Comment: @Peter But there is little reason to believe in fairness of the die either... (given that it's the first ever dice produced by this printer and fairness of a die is very sensitive to small variations in shape).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the probability that your die is fair is zero, because even, say, a probability of $1/6+10^{-100}$ for getting a 6 would not be a fair die. If you want a non-zero probability, you need to specify acceptable deviations from the fair die.

Comment: @cel I don't see how you can consider "probability of getting a 6" as an inherent property of a die since the outcome of the throw depends not only on the die itself but on mechanics of the throw - which automatically leads to a limit in how well you can differentiate different dice. Basically, no number of throws will ever distinguish $1/6$ from $1/6+10^{-100}$ due to fluctuations in the throw itself and unclear relationship between die bias, throw distribution and outcome.

Comment: As an illustration of Pearson's $\chi^2$ test, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Examples) presents just such a discussion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Goodness-of-fit test.** Computation in R. Results agree with Comment by @Peter.

```
 obs = c(21, 30, 23, 31, 21, 24)
 chisq.test(obs)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

 data:  obs 
 X-squared = 3.92, df = 5, p-value = 0.561
```

If observed counts are $X_i$ and expected counts are $E = 150/6 = 25,$
Then the chi-squared goodness-of-fit statistic is
$Q = \sum_{i=1}^6 (X_i - E)^2/E,$ which is approximately
distributed as $Chisq(DF = 5).$ The critical value for a
test at level 5% is 11.07. We fail to reject the null hypothesis
that all six faces are equally likely because $Q = 3.92 < 11.07.$

**Power.** However, I'm wondering if 150 rolls is enough. Suppose your
die is markedly biased so that faces 1, 2, and 3 each have probability 5/36 and faces 4, 5, and 6 each have probability 7/36. Then the following
simulation shows that only about 27 in 100 tests with 150 rolls
would reject the hypothesis of fairness. That is, the power of
the goodness-of-fit test against this particular degree of bias
is about 27%. More modestly biased dice would fail the test at an even lower rate.

```
 m = 10^5;  q = numeric(m); E = 150/6
 for(i in 1:m) {
   faces = sample(1:6, 150, repl=T, prob=c(5,5,5,7,7,7)/36)
   x = table(faces);  q[i]=sum((x-E)^2/E)}
 mean(q > qchisq(.96, 5))
 ## 0.2702
```

The histogram shows values of $Q$ for 100,000 tests, each using 150 rolls of such a biased die. The vertical line is the critical value for a test at level 5%. The curve is the density of $Chisq(5)$.

[image]

Prompted by a comment, I ran a slight modification of the R code that shows
89% power for the same biased die as above, but using 600 rolls for the test. The corresponding graph is shown below.[image]

*Note*: I have posted a Bayesian analysis of the data for face 1
[separately](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584833/bayesian-approach-is-a-die-from-a-3-d-printer-fair).

Comment: How many rolls would i roughly need to to have a 90% chance that the test is right an a die that is biased only 5% so 5.6 or 6.4. Also what would happen if there are only 2 sides that are different e.g. 1 and 6 with 5/36 and 7/36 respectively and the rest is 1/6?

Comment: It would require several more simulations to answer such questions. The R code is easy to modify, but each run takes a couple of minutes on my ancient computer. For a 150 rolls, the power against the alternative distribution (1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 2/9, 2/9, 2/9) is about 90%. But that is an _extremely_ biased die. You are right to suppose that power depends on degree of biasedness and number of rolls.

Comment: @Eumel As a ball-park, consider that to distinguish $B(n,p)$ and $B(n,p+\epsilon)$ you need $n\gg p(1-p)\epsilon^{-2}$, so you need at least $750$ tests.